# How can we make our iPhone App HIPAA compliant?

Tags: ios, hipaa, encryption

I wanted to develop an iOS App for managing medical records.How can we make our iPhone App HIPAA compliant?

**UPDATE:**  Is there any specific Encryption Algorithm you would suggest to safeguard EMR ?

Comment: Note that you'll definitely need to consult with legal counsel before being certain that your application is HIPAA compliant. As such, I don't believe that we're the right crowd to ask this, so I'm of the opinion this is off topic for the site.

Comment: The answers to [Web site HIPAA compliance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506354/web-site-hipaa-compliance) all end up stating that you'll need to talk with a lawyer about this.